# User cannot login after account is created

Tags: c, cs50

I am trying to work on a simple app on my own in C. It facilitates anybody to create an account of his/her and save her personal information and that is secure.. Till now user can make an account of his/her while when the user comes back at logging he cannot. I have written and used the file I/O to save user credentials..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cs50.h"

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    // The pointer to the File
    FILE* accountsDatabase = fopen("accountsDatabase.txt", "r+");

    char Fdecision;
    char Gateway = 'Y';
    char Gatewaydenied = 'N';

    string stringGateway = "Yes";
    string stringGatewayDenied = "No";
    string information;
    string Newusername;
    string Newpassword;
    string Universalpassword;
    string Universalusername;

    printf("\n \t \n");

    printf("\tThis is Dell login interference.....");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\t#################################\n");
    printf("\t#################################\n");

    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf(" Please inset your id and password in below user friendly interface.");
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n");

    printf("Please type answer in Y and N");
    printf("\n");
    printf("Do you want the Dell's login user interfae: ");
    Fdecision = GetChar();

    if (Fdecision == Gateway)
    {
        printf("Do you want to create a new user. Answer in Yes or NO: ");
        string userChoice = GetString();
        printf("\n");
        if (strcmp(stringGateway, userChoice) == 0)
        {
            printf("To create a New User Account.... Fill following boxes..\n");
            printf("\n");
            printf("username: ");
            Newusername = GetString();
            printf("password: ");
            Newpassword = GetString();
            printf("\n");
            printf("Your personal textBook..:: ");
            information = GetString();
            printf("\n");
            // Checks if it is opened..
            if (accountsDatabase == NULL)
            {
                printf("Error opening file:\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fputs(Newusername, accountsDatabase);
                fputs(Newpassword, accountsDatabase);
            }
            printf("Do you want to login.? Answer in Yes or No: ");
            string LoginDecision = GetString();
            if(strcmp(stringGateway, LoginDecision) == 0)
            {
                printf("Username: ");
                string username = GetString();
                printf("\n");
                if (strcmp(Newusername, username) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Password: ");
                    string password = GetString();
                    if (strcmp(Newpassword, Newpassword) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("Confirming Identity.....\n");
                        printf("Identity Confirmed.....\n");
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("Do you want to reveal your sensitive information: ");
                        string secondDecision = GetString();
                        if (strcmp (stringGateway, secondDecision) == 0)
                        {
                            printf("\n");
                            printf("Enter password:: ");
                            string Currentpassword = GetString();
                            if (strcmp (Newpassword, Currentpassword) == 0)
                            {
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("%s\n", information);
                                printf("\n\n");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else if (strcmp(stringGatewayDenied, userChoice) == 0)
        {
            printf("\n");
            printf("Username: ");
            string username = GetString();
            printf("\n");


            // Checks if it is opened..
            if (accountsDatabase == NULL)
            {

                printf("Error opening file:\n");
            }
            else
            {
                fgets(Universalusername, "%s", accountsDatabase);


                if (strcmp(Universalusername, username) == 0)
                {
                    printf("Password: ");
                    string password = GetString();

                    if (strcmp(Universalpassword, password) == 0)
                    {
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("Confirming Identity.....\n");
                        printf("Identity Confirmed.....\n");
                        printf("\n");
                        printf("Do you want to reveal your sensitive information: ");
                        string secondDecision = GetString();
                        if (strcmp (stringGateway, secondDecision) == 0)
                        {
                            printf("\n");
                            printf("Enter password:: ");
                            string Currentpassword = GetString();
                            if (strcmp (Universalpassword, Currentpassword) == 0)
                            {
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("%s\n", information);
                                printf("\n\n");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
            printf("Universalusername : %s", Universalusername);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Take these security measures...\n");
            printf("##############################");
            printf("\n");
            printf(" 1) You need specil previlage to access sensitive information...\n");
            printf(" 2) Please run in a minute either alarm will be trigered..\n");
            printf(" 3) Security camera are availabel, \n 4) run now.\n");
        }

    }
    else if (Fdecision == Gatewaydenied)
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("You can get off from front door.\n");
        printf("Don't LOok Back, it's not safe..\n'");
        printf("What do you think? Can you cheat me? \n");
        printf("No, you cannot!");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("\n");
        printf("Please choose between Yes (Y) or No (N)\n");
        printf("Not the full spelling but ony a single abbreviated letter..\n");
        printf("Y or N..\n");
    }

    fclose(accountsDatabase);
}
```

Comment: 1. `string` is a bad idea for a `typedef` because a) It's not clear that you are dealing with a pointer. b) There is no string type in c, understanding how strings are represented in c is fundamental to any c programmer. 2. That's what Torvalds meant with more than 3 levels of indentation, it's quite hard to understand your code without comments and with it's current structure.

Comment: I agree with @iharob, your sw is very complicated to read. First: you do not load the file at startup so you cannot check if the user is already present or not in your db file. You do not allocate any structure to represent it and mainly you do not allocate and manage char * pointer correctly.

Comment: @gaemaf And ignoring the return value of `fopen()` is another very bad thing in this code.

Comment: Maybe my code is looking very odd. but @iharob I will keep your suggestion, I converted string to an array of char and now it works. Thanks

Comment: can some one tell me what is the relation between `string` and `Torvalds 3 levels of indentation`? i am really confused!!!

Answer (score -2):

your code is not so clear nor easy to read. to help you, i wrote this piece of code that you can use it in your daily codding and that can make your life easier. wish this can help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>



input(char *prompt,char *buff);
int YesNoQuetion(char *prompt);

int main (void)
{
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50];
    printf("This is a little code that will help you create a clean code\n\n");
    printf("Please enter your first and last name\n");

    input("First name",firstname);
    input("Last name",lastname);

    if (YesNoQuetion("Do you realy want to know?"))
    {
       printf("\nThat's good '%s, %s', you just pressed Yes\n",firstname,lastname);
    }
    else{
         printf("\nYou answerd No, that is also good\n");;
    }

  return 0;
}

 /*__________________________________________________________________________________
*/
int YesNoQuetion(char *prompt){
    int r=0,c;
    printf("%s (Y/N) : ",prompt);
    while(1){
        c=_getch();
        if(c=='n' || c=='N' || c=='y' || c=='Y'){
            printf("%c\x8",c);
            r=c;
        }else{
            if( (c=='\n'||c=='\r') && r)
                break;
            r=0;
            printf("%d\x8\x7",c);
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n",(r=='y'|| r=='Y')?"Yes":"No");
    return (r=='y'|| r=='Y');

}
  /*__________________________________________________________________________________
*/
int input(char *prompt,char *buff){
    printf("%s :\t",prompt);
    return scanf("%s",buff);
}

/*__________________________________________________________________________________
*/
```

Comment: If you wrote this piece of code from scratch why did you write it like that? You can imrove readability a little bit more.

Comment: @iharob, i already have spell checker and code formater that is called Astyle. i don't need an other one that is called iharob. every time i face you, you are complaining. do something helpful.

Comment: I do helpful things, that's why I have good reputation. I just hate ugly code so much. I also don't like your logic.

Comment: @iharob, i know i have an ugly logic and code, i wish i can see yours.

Comment: You can, there are lots of answers of mine with code or critics to style and logic.